# Is DataGridView remembering references?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I use a System.Windows.Forms.**DataGridView** control **without** data binding.

The following code is working and OK. I create a list, add an element and assign it to the DGV. The current cell will not be null - perfect!

```csharp
List<string> list = new List<string>();  // create an empty list
list.Add("test");                        // adding a new item to the list
dataGridView.DataSource = list;          // assign list as datasource
var cell = dataGridView.CurrentCell;     // cell is not null -> that's expected and OK
```

**Now the problem**. When I have an empty list first assigned to the DGV it will somehow remembers the reference of the list, **although when I reset it to null before**... why?

```csharp
List<string> list = new List<string>();  // create an empty list
dataGridView.DataSource = list;          // assign list as datasource BEFORE ADDING element
dataGridView.DataSource = null;          // assign null to reset

list.Add("test");                        // adding a new item to the list
dataGridView.DataSource = list;          // assign list again as datasource
var cell = dataGridView.CurrentCell;     // cell is null, but it SHOULD NOT BE
```

Why is the DGV not setting the CurrentCell? Is it somehow remembering the list and that it was empty?

Thanx for any answer.

-jaz

Comment: Clicking on it will raise a OutOfRangeException with index -1.

Comment: Of course does the grid throw exceptions of it's own. Checkout the framework code with ILSpy. The DGV has tonnes of ArgumentOutOfRangeException's to be thrown.

Comment: I don't think it remembers the reference, however I believe that CurrentCell is not properly updated when datasource of DGV is updated.  

If you will gp through code of DataGridView.cs from (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridView.cs), you will observe that It clears the current cell on setting the DataSource, but somehow new value is not updated.

I will update here if I find something more.

Answer (score 0):

I could see that the data source saves the reference. So if you set the datasource to null the list is null as well.